Error Getting Access token with Managed Identity
Hi do you have any example of using managed identity (without credential secret) with MSAL to retrieve access token for Dynamics 365 in python? Does the module currently support ManageIdentity?
I have tried with the following code and receiving the error saying could not connect to server
import msal
    
def useManagedIdentityCredential(environment_url, tenant_id,client_id,authority,scopes):
    credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id = client_id, client_credential = None, authority = authority)
    token = credential.get_token(scopes)
    
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    environment_api_url = f"https://{environment}.api.crm.dynamics.com"
    environment_url = f"https://{environment}.crm.dynamics.com"
    authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource="+environment_url
        
    scope = f"{environment_url}/.default" 
    my_client_id = <my object id>
    tenant_id = <tenant_id>
        
      
    useManagedIdentityCredential(environment_url, tenant_id, my_client_id, graph_authority, scope)




Note that: Managed identity does not support generating token for Dynamics CRM API.

The supported audience are: https://management.core.windows.net/,https://management.azure.com/,https://graph.windows.net/,https://vault.azure.net,https://datalake.azure.net/,https://outlook.office365.com/,https://graph.microsoft.com/,https://batch.core.windows.net/,https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api,https://storage.azure.com/,https://rest.media.azure.net,https://api.loganalytics.io,https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net,https://www.yammer.com,https://digitaltwins.azure.net,0b07f429-9f4b-4714-9392-cc5e8e80c8b0,822c8694-ad95-4735-9c55-256f7db2f9b4,https://dev.azuresynapse.net,https://database.windows.net,https://quantum.microsoft.com,https://iothubs.azure.net,2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d,https://azuredatabricks.net/,ce34e7e5-485f-4d76-964f-b3d2b16d1e4f,https://azure-devices-provisioning.net,https://managedhsm.azure.net,499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798,https://api.adu.microsoft.com/,https://purview.azure.net/,6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630,https://cognitiveservices.azure.com,48ac35b8-9aa8-4d74-927d-1f4a14a0b239,46da2f7e-b5ef-422a-88d4-2a7f9de6a0b2"
Hence as a workaround you can make use Service Principal or Microsoft Entra ID application to access the Dynamics CRM API like below:

Use the below code to generate the access token:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

tenant_id = "TenantID"
client_id = "ClientID"
client_secret = "ClientSecret"
scopes = ["https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/.default"]

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id,client_secret)
token = credential.get_token(*scopes)

if token:
    print("Access token:", token.token)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve access token.")


By using the above access token you can call the API.
